# Clickable HTML iframe containers with Elementor Builder: What am I missing?

Tags: html, css

Please how can i make an html iframe container content clickable.

I'm using elementor builder, wrapper link didn't work, i am displaying different small box contents on my website through iframes but i just can't map them to their pages i need the iframe container to link to a url when clicked, i'm an amateur.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can not really use an iframe "as a link." But you are of course free to make the iframe _content_ link somewhere.

Comment: I created a new empty container with same width and height positioned on top the iframe container then wrapper link worked, but google refused to index the page reason: clickable elements too close now I have to make the iframe standalone and clickable.